# How to convert SQL rows to an array of json objects in Azure Data Factory?

Tags: sql, api, azure-data-factory, dataflow

I'm working on a **Azure Data Factory Pipeline** and have following challenge currently:
I'd like to make an API call (Post) which requires some data with the syntax of `array` and in it, multiple `objects`.

Now - both, the data retrieving (from `SQL` db) and `API` call work when used independently (In case of the API call: I've been using hardcoded mock data for the body). The challenge is in connecting both of them. That means:
I'd like to get multiple rows out of a SQL table, convert them to the required json structure  and fill that data then into the API call.
See picture below:

[image]

In simple steps explained again:

1. Get rows from SQL table
2. Convert each row into an object e.g. `{ "somekey": valueOfRow}`
3. Collect all objects in an `array`
4. Provide `array` to `API` call

I'm just unsure how to proceed with the connection.

**Additional Information**

As requested, some further detailed information.

Currently the API call uses following hardcoded mockdata:

```json
[{"idType": "ID_ISIN", "idValue": "US0123456789" }]
```

From the dataflow I'll get rows with one column called `isin` (with row values such as `US0123456789`)

The goal is to fill API's body dynamically such that it receives something like this:

```json
[
    {
        "idType": "ID_ISIN", 
        "idValue": "US0123456789" 
    },
    {
        "idType": "ID_ISIN", 
        "idValue": "US9876543210" 
    },
    {...}

]
```

I saw that one can achieve something similiar with `SQL` query - see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/json-features?view=azuresql

But I'd miss the part `"idType": "ID_ISIN"` in each row/object.

Comment: Can you please confirm these: What does the dataflow activity in the given image do? And how may rows are you getting from SQL database?

Comment: I intentionally did not add more information to not distract from the core issue. But to answer your questions: The dataflow activity just accesses a SQL table and applies a filter (since I'm not interested in all rows). There's no sink. And right now only 1 row since I'm just testing but in the future it should handle anything between 1 and 100 rows (the api does not support more data point than 100).

Comment: Can you please provide the Hardcoded mock data (array of objects) that you have been using for API call

Comment: I added some additional information - let me know if something needs further clarification

Comment: So, here `idType` and `idValue` are the names of columns in your SQL table? Or `ID_ISIN` is the column name and `US0123456789` is its value

Comment: No, `isin` is a column name in my database. And `idType` and `idValue` is the "interface" of the API. `US0123456789` is a value of the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using dataflow to retrieve records and create an array of objects (where each object is row from SQL table) might not be the right way to achieve your requirement.

- We can use `Lookup` activity which returns the rows based on given table or query as an array of objects. Look at the following demonstration.
- The following is the data in my table `repro1` which I am going to use (we only need ID_ISIN column).

[image]

- In your data factory studio, create a new lookup activity. Create a new source dataset for your SQL database table and click OK.
  [image]
- Uncheck `First Row only` checkbox. There is no need to select a table here, instead we can just query from the required table based on requirement. Therefore, check the `Query` box.
- Now, I have written the following query to extract data as required from the `repro1` table (such that it would give results which are in line with hardcoded mock data).

```
select 'ID_ISIN' as idType, ID_ISIN as idValue from repro1
```

[image]

- Now when I debug the pipeline, you can see the debug output of the lookup activity.
  [image]
- The above output consists of lot of other information along with the rows returned as a result of given query.
- Now you can directly retrieve the above highlighted array of objects using the following dynamic content (if your lookup activity name is Lookup1).

```
@activity('Lookup1').output.value
```

You can use the above dynamic content (an array of objects) to fill your API call's body.

Comment: It worked! Makes totally sense how you approached this.